# ImportError: No module named MySQLdb even when Mysqldb is installed

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

So I have Mysql installed on my Linux. After that I installed mysqldb using the command sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb. Then when I try to import it in python I get the error "ImportError: No module named MySQLdb". I even rebooted and all. I am running python 2.7. Is there something else that I need to do before getting this to work? Any suggestion? Thanks in advance !!

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

The output of pip freeze is

```
Cython==0.21
DataShape==0.3.0
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
PIL==1.1.7
PyYAML==3.11
Pygments==1.6
SQLAlchemy==0.9.7
Sphinx==1.2.3
Theano==0.6.0
Werkzeug==0.9.6
XlsxWriter==0.5.7
abstract-rendering==0.5.1
argcomplete==0.8.1
astropy==0.4.2
atom==0.3.9
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
binstar==0.7.1
bitarray==0.8.1
blaze==0.6.3
blz==0.6.2
bokeh==0.6.1
boto==2.32.1
casuarius==1.1
cdecimal==2.3
cffi==0.8.6
chaco==4.4.1
colorama==0.3.1
conda==3.7.0
conda-build==1.8.2
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==0.5.4
cytoolz==0.7.0
decorator==3.4.0
docutils==0.12
enable==4.3.0
enaml==0.9.8
future==0.13.1
futures==2.1.6
gensim==0.10.3
gevent==1.0.1
gevent-websocket==0.9.3
greenlet==0.4.4
grin==1.2.1
h5py==2.3.1
ipython==2.2.0
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.0
kiwisolver==0.1.3
llvmpy==0.12.7
lxml==3.4.0
matplotlib==1.4.0
mock==1.0.1
mpi4py==1.3
multipledispatch==0.4.7
networkx==1.9.1
nltk==3.0.0
nose==1.3.4
numba==0.14.0
numexpr==2.3.1
numpy==1.9.2
openpyxl==1.8.5
pandas==0.14.1
patsy==0.3.0
pep8==1.5.7
ply==3.4
psutil==2.1.1
py==1.4.25
pyOpenSSL==0.14
pycosat==0.6.1
pycparser==2.10
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.19.5
pyface==4.4.0
pyflakes==0.8.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
pytest==2.6.3
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2014.7
pyzmq==14.3.1
redis==2.9.1
requests==2.4.1
rope==0.9.4
runipy==0.1.1
scikit-image==0.10.1
scikit-learn==0.15.2
scipy==0.14.0
six==1.8.0
sockjs-tornado==1.0.1
spyder==2.3.1
statsmodels==0.5.0
sympy==0.7.5
tables==3.1.1
toolz==0.7.0
tornado==4.0.2
traits==4.4.0
traitsui==4.4.0
ujson==1.33
unicodecsv==0.9.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlrd==0.9.3
xlwt==0.7.5
```

Comment: What is the output of `$ pip freeze`?

Comment: `pip install MySQL-python`

Comment: go to your site-packages folder, is it there?

Comment: Good grief, is that what's installed on your system Python? You should absolutely check out [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @IanAuld Sorry, but what is the problem?

Comment: @Ajay It says Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MySQL-python in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: You shouldn't be installing things, especially that many, to your system Python. There can be name clashes and some of the packages may not play nice. It's much safer to use `virtualenv` to create a separate Python environment so you only install the packages you need for each project. Causing damage to your system Python can cause you to experience problems with your OS, for Mac and *INX environments anyway. I don't think Windows relies on Python in anyway.

Comment: @IanAuld Oh, I see, I'll check out virtualenv. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import the mysql python module:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: I already installed it using sudo apt-get. On doing using pip it shows:Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MySQL-python in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages